# Download data from ftp server of ENA database using accession numbers

Tags: python, r, database, ftp, bioinformatics

I would like to download complete protein sequences of some organisms given in ENA database (under genomes at ENA section) with the information I have i.e. around 2500 accession numbers.

I tried to dig deeper to find them in ftp server using taxonomy division and all. but could not find anything relevant. Downloading them one by one would not be an ideal solution.

Hence could you guys help me if you know any packages in R or python do this for me?

Comment: Please, send link to the specific page containing the data you want to download. Most programmers on this site have not used ENA database. You can also provide steps for downloading one by one. After all these could be the steps to be automated with a script.

Comment: you can easily do this with a REST API which is supported by ENA..., have you tried any coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my subjective problem:

```
curl -F accessions=@<input_file_path> http://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/data/download?
display=<output_format> 
-o<output_file_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this old script of mine might be useful.

One thing to note is that the genomes are downloaded from NCBI and not ENA, but I think a lot of these databases sync their data across each other. So you might still find what your looking for.

If you specifically only want to download those genomes from the given accession numbers (~2500), then this *might* not work (unless you possibly do a filter on the returned `search_results` before downloading; `Entrez.efetch`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Bio import Entrez

search_term = raw_input("Organism name: ")

Entrez.email = "your_email@isp.com"   # required by NCBI
search_handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nucleotide", term=search_term, usehistory="y", property='complete genome')
search_results = Entrez.read(search_handle)
search_handle.close()

gi_list = search_results["IdList"]
count = int(search_results["Count"])
webenv = search_results["WebEnv"]
query_key = search_results["QueryKey"]

batch_size = 5    # download sequences in batches so NCBI doesn't time you out

with open("ALL_SEQ.fasta", "w") as out_handle:
    for start in range(0, count, batch_size):
        end = min(count, start+batch_size)
        print "Going to download record %i to %i" % (start+1, end)
        fetch_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", rettype="fasta", retmode="text",retstart=start, retmax=batch_size, webenv=webenv, query_key=query_key)
        data = fetch_handle.read()
        fetch_handle.close()
        out_handle.write(data)

print ("\nDownload completed")
```